# Detect if point is inside a building in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I wanted to detect if I have a marker at a given Lat/Lng , is this position inside a building or any infrastructure. Like the map at @ http://web.iiit.ac.in/~jayesh.lahori/map.png has two markers red & blue, both are a part of any building/infrastructure.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is create a polygon for your building, and then test if your point is inside the building.

```
building = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: buildingCoords,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0, //invisible
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0 //invisible
  });

yourPointCoords = {
        lat : 12.78272115660313,
        long : 6.872586727142334
    }

if(google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(yourPointCoords, building)) {
    //your business
}
```

Comment: But, the problem here is that point's location is not static, I want it to be dynamic. So scenario is, given a point I have to check if this lies inside any building. i.e., neither building nor points location are fixed. Any other suggestions ??

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Google Maps API entry for reverse geocoding

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ReverseGeocoding